# Script Request - Windows 10 Total Printer Reset Including Registry

Tags: windows, printing, spooler

Please can anyone point me in the right direction to a script for Windows 10 / 11 that will completely reset the print services on a machine? Rewrites the registry control set etc.

Tried and tested would be great.

Cheers